# Prevent Windows Sharing event to my App from Refreshing to the Start Route

Tags: windows, reactjs, web-applications

Windows App (written in React as a PWA) refreshes to the start path before every activate event.

When an open app has a share link to MyApp, click on it and the destination app flickers.

If the Windows Mail app is open and has a MyApp link in the email.

How prevent MyApp from refreshing/flickering before responding to the share event?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter PWA code:

```
//Without this, the app will first refresh to the start path before every activate event
window.MSApp.pageHandlesAllApplicationActivations(true);

//This must not be defferd so that it can recieve the initial 'activated' event in time
window.Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener(
 'activated', e=>
  microsoftInterfaceLoader()/then(mi => {
    mi.handleActivatedEventFactory(e);
}));
```

Courtesy of [@charliecroom](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Speakers/charlie-croom) at [MSBuild 2018 Modernizing Twitter PWA](https://youtu.be/D9AM7bafSrI?t=1036)